# Clustering data multiple times to get statistics

Tags: statistical-significance, clustering, mean, k-means

Suppose I have some data (objects described by a number of variables like diameter, etc...) and that I want to run K-means clustering on it.

Suppose now that I run the algorithm multiple times (1) on the same data set, and that at each iteration I save, for instance, the mean and standard deviation of $\texttt{diameter}$ for the objects in each found cluster:

```
Iteration Cluster_I_mean Cluster_I_SD Cluster_II_mean ...
1         3.3            0.1          6.7             ...
2         3.6            0.7          6.1             ...
...
```

At the end, I can take the mean of Cluster_I_mean values to obtain an *overall* mean value.

Does this help me find better statistics (like a more *robust* mean of $\texttt{diameter}$ for cluster I)?

(1) I am not talking about, for instance, $\texttt{n_init}$ in Scikit-learn, but running the same cell of my notebook multiple times and append the results.

Comment: Wouldn't this be of interest only if you're studying the *algorithm* rather than the data??

Answer (score 1):

**No**, this does not make much sense.

The clusters found during each run of the algorithm may be completely different. Even if you have two perfectly separated data clusters, A and B, in one run K-means may fit cluster 1 to A and cluster 2 to B, and in the next run the other way around. You would probably end up with all "robust" cluster means having the same value as mean of the data.

Answer (score 1):

No.

By the concept of k-means, use only the best solution.

Your estimates of some cluster "diameter" do not get more accurate by using inferior solutions coming from potentially completely different local minima.

If you want a robust diameter, define what the diameter is, then consider robust variants of that statistic. For example, take the 95% percentile of the paiewise distances.